# Find a basis and dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find a basis and the dimension of the vector space (on $R$) generated by

$\lbrace u + v + w ; v + w + z ; w + z + u ; z + u + v \rbrace$,

where $u,v,w,z$ are linearly independent vectors (from a vector space).

Can somebody explain please, how do I solve this?

Comment: The structure of those sums is particularly simple. You should be able to use that to get an answer very quickly. DonAntonio's approach is a more general one that is very good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Form the coefficients' matrix wrt the basis $\;\{u,v,w,z\}\;$ and reduce it:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&1\\
1&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&1\\
0&\!\!-1&0&1\\
0&0&\!\!-1&1\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&2\\
0&0&\!\!-1&1\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&2\\
0&0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$$

so ...

Comment: so basically the basis is $\lbrace (1,1,1,0), (0,1,1,1),(0,0,1,2),(0,0,0,2)  \rbrace$ and the dimension is 4?

Comment: Well, you want **one** basis (which includes as many linearly idnependent vectors as the subspace's dimension), and yes.